# Do any programming languages provide the ability to name the return value of a function?

Tags: return-value, programming-languages, naming-conventions

Quite commonly while programming I find it necessary to document the value that a function returns. In Java/Scala world, you often use comments above the function to do this.

However, this can stand out in contrast to the first-class documentation that function *parameters* get in all languages. For example:

```
def exponent(base: Int, power: Int): Int
```

Here we have the signature for a method that raises `base` to the power `power` and returns... *probably the result of that computation*? I know for certain it returns an `Int`, and it seems quite reasonable to *infer* that the return value is indeed the result of calculating `base ^ power`, but in many functions I've written and read it is not possible to infer the return value's semantic meaning quite so easily and you need to study the documentation and/or actually **use** the method to find out.

Which leads me to wonder, do any languages provide support for optionally declaring a *semantic name* for the return value?

```
def exponent(base: Int, power: Int): Int(exitCode)
```

A hah! Turns out this function actually returns an indication of whether the operation succeeded or failed! Look it is so clear right there in the method signature! My IDE could also intelligently create a variable with the same name when I call this method, a la:

```
// Typing in IntelliJ
exponent(5, 5)<TAB>

// Autocompletes to:
val exitCode = exponent(5, 5)
```

I'm not under any illusion that this is some sort of ground-breaking idea, but it seems like it could be generally useful, and I'm struck that I have never seen this concept implemented in any programming language.

Can you name any single programming language that *does* have this kind of semantic naming of return values?

Comment: Contextual side-note on this question: I am *not* looking for programming language recommendations. This question is *not* opinion-based, because whether or not there exists a programming language with this design characteristic is not an opinion. This question is – essentially – research into the capabilities of programming languages on planet earth; I thought I may have identified a simple feature that does not exist and so even a single counter-example, as is given below, answers the question definitively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In APL, for instance, the result of a function is declared as a variable. The function declaration in your example could be written like

```
exitCode ← base exponent power
```

in APL. However, a function with no side effects should always be named after the result it returns. If the function can fail I would use a value that is never returned on success, for instance -1 in this case.

Comment: Excellent! Thank you for this answer. Yeah I used the `exitCode` example specifically because the result is surprising, unintuitive, and bad practice; exactly the kind of scenario where naming your return type would have high value.

Answer (score 1):

Golang has this feature as [named return values](https://go.dev/tour/basics/7) (from *A Tour of Go*).

Your example of function declaration in Golang:

```golang
package main

func exponent(base int, power int) (exitCode int)
{
    // statements...
    exitCode = 0
    return
}

func main() {
    exitCode := exponent(5, 5)
}
```

And we may add another return value to get the result too:

```golang
package main

import (
    "math"
)

func exponent(base int, power int) (result int, exitCode int)
{
    // statements...
    result = int(math.Pow(float64(base), float64(power)))
    exitCode = 0
    return
}

func main() {
    result, exitCode := exponent(5, 5)
}
```

Also see [this question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/148135/named-outputs-of-a-function).